# How to disable google web viewer full screen option

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

i am using embedded google viewer with iframe to display pdf,i want to remove full screen popout from it and how could i disable right click in iframe.

itried doing many thing but nothing is working out,my pdf's url are store in db.

and my code is

```
   <iframe id="display" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" style="width:1000px; height:1000px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

i tried changing the css like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = jQuery("#display").contents().find("aria-label").css( "display", "none" );
```

Someone help me out please

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing same issue with google docs viewer, got the solution by using CSS:

```
div[role="toolbar"] {
    display: none;
}
```

It hides the popout div of google docs viewer.